# Authorizing a HttpClient Request

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies, dotnet-httpclient

I'm trying to access twitter user's `followers` page, but the content isn't available to guests.

```
using (var res = await http.GetAsync("http://www.twitter.com/" + handle + "/followers"))
{
    followers = new List<string>();
    ...
    // res returns a login page
```

Is there any simple way to authorize my request in ASP.NET? Can I somehow use cookies of a client that is sending a request to my ASP.NET page?

Okay, that's a stupid idea. Is there anything else that would work?

Answer (score 0):

I do it like this:

```
var authenticationCookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];
```

and then use the authenticationCookie to call the API on user's behalf.

Comment: Okay, but how is that supposed to authorize twitter account?